# Cannot display the relational tables category news

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo the data from a table that is related with a table of categories, but I am not getting this to display the data, somethings wrong.

Here is some code:

tbl_category_news
- id_category_news
- category

tbl_news
- id_news
- id_category_news
-title
-description
-msg
-name_arquive
-legend

```
 <?php
     $categoryId = 1; 
      $sql_visualizar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_news AS t1 JOIN tbl_category_news c
    ON c.id_category_news=t1.id_category_news WHERE id_category_news = {$categoryId}");
    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql_visualizar)){
    $title = $linha ['title'];
    $description = $linha['description'];
    $msg = $linha['msg'];
    $legend = $linha['legend'];
    $nome_arquive = $linha['name_arquive'];
    $id_news = $linha['id_news'];

      ?>
<?php echo $msg?>
<?php
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing `WHERE id_category_news = {$categoryId} with WHERE t1.id_category_news = $categoryId`

Comment: at the end of mysql_query write or die(mysql_error()) then check.
Also check mysql_num_rows to check how many rows are retrieved